# Duplicate commits in the network on GitHub

Tags: github, git-rebase

What I have:

https://github.com/kayuri/HNC/network

The two repositories are in sync.

[image: The repositories]

How we can make `kayuri` repo containing a linear history of commits without any merges, and `nponeccop` repo containing no commits at all (because they are all already in the upstream `kayuri` repo?

My local repo was created by git `clone` of `nponeccop`, and it has two remotes: `origin` (that is `nponeccop`) and I added `kayuri` later.

I want to reposition  `nponeccop` so it starts on the last commit of `kayuri`

I have `kayuri` and `origin` listed as remotes:

```
$ git remote -v
kayuri  git://github.com/kayuri/HNC.git (fetch)
kayuri  git://github.com/kayuri/HNC.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:nponeccop/HNC.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:nponeccop/HNC.git (push)
```

Now if I do `git rebase kayuri` I get an error:

```
$ git rebase kayuri
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream kayuri
```

There is only one 'master' branch in the local repo. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I meant git rebase `kayuri/master`: ie rebase your own master branch on top of the other remote master branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you consider the history:

[image: network graph]

If `nponeccop` contains commits already present on `kayuri`, then, when on repo `nponeccop`, a simple:

```
git checkout master
git fetch kayuri 
git rebase kayuri/master
git push -f origin master
```

should be enough to replay only the delta on top of the remote named `nponeccop` (ie you add `nponeccop` as a remote for the repo `kayuri`).
Any common commit won't be replayed twice, and will simply be ignored.

Note that this will rewrite the history of commit in your own master branch, hence the `push -f`.  If you are several people working on the `nponeccop` repo, that might be a problem for the other users.